# How to find where a song occurs in a video with ffmpeg/ffprobe

Tags: video, ffmpeg, music

I have a audio file (mp3) and a video file (mp4).

I need to find out where the song starts and ends in the video (Eg. @ 0-60 seconds). How would I do this with ffmpeg/ffprobe? If this is not possible with ffmpeg, are there any other ways to compare audio streams?

Note that the audio quality in the song from the mp3 is not exactly the same from the audio quality in the song from video.

Comment: Perhaps [chromaprint](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#chromaprint-1) could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I use the volumedetect filter to find the max_volume for every 5 seconds of  video file.

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -ss <Start Seconds> -i <Input File> -t 5 -filter:a volumedetect -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep max_volume
```

When the max_volume goes over -20DB, I know that the song began and when it falls below -20DB I know that it ended.

Hope this helps!